# Manage Jenkins configuration for Global pipleline with SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I need to run **declarative pipeline **with** SVN in Jenkins**.I'm getting the below error.
Dont know if my **Manage Jenkins configuration** is wrong or my **Jenkins job configuration** is faulty.Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Some background,I have created the "jenkinsfile" in https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/resources/jenkinsfile & "first.groovy" in https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/vars/first.groovy.

Configured Manage Jenkins -> Configure System for the Global Pipeline libraries

But I'm getting the below error-

****Started by user 
Obtained jenkinsfile from svn https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/resources
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
Loading library test@trunk
Location '**https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/trunk' does not exist**
Cleaning local Directory .
Checking out https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/trunk at revision '2020-12-10T07:21:25.316 +0000'
Using sole credentials jenkins-gh-pri@appsian.com/****** (newJenkinsSvnConn) in realm ‘https://svn.gh.pri:443 Appsian(PRD) SVN’
ERROR: Failed to check out https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E170000: URL 'https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/trunk' doesn't exist****

[Jenkins Job Configuration & Manage Jenkins settings Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt771.png)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Got it working!!

Below is the Manage Jenkins->Configure System settings for SVN

[![Manage Jenkins settings][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Some details about the settings:-

https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac - is the svn path
https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/vars/<>.groovy
https://<>/svn/ops/jenkins/paac/resources/jenkinsfile
test - is the Library name as mentioned in JenkinsFile
vars - is the dir which contains your groovy
*Note - Jenkins job configuration remains the same as the screenshot!*
```